# Is there a chance to get the size of a list property in Struts 2?

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, displaytag, ognl

Is there a chance to get the size of a property which is a list?

```jsp
<display:column property="reminderSend" title="Anzahl der Mahnungen" 
                sortable="true" />
```

`reminderSet` is a list. I want to display the size of it and not the values.

Comment: You want the list size to be printed on each row ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OGNL even has a pseudo-property for collections. Suppose you have `uid="row"` on the table then

```
<display:column title="Anzahl der Mahnungen">
  <s:property value="%{#attr.row.reminderSend.size}"/>
</display:column>
```